# Are locally compact group having a abelian normal subgroup of finite index amenable?

Tags: group-theory

Given a group $G$ which is locally compact (possibly Hausdorff) with an abelian normal subgroup $A$ of finite index is this group $G$ then amenable?

I think it is true but I have no argument for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $G$ be our group, and $A$ be a normal abelian group of finite index in $G$.

We know three facts about amenability:

- Abelian groups are amenable
- Finite groups are amenable
- Group extensions of an amenable group by an amenable group is again amenable.

Since $G$ can be seen as a group extension of $G/A$ by $A$, these properties imply that $G$ is also amenable.

---

Note that this is true if $A$ is just amenable, not necessarily abelian.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, of course: if $H$ is amenable (and abelian groups are) and $H<G$ with finite index then $G$ is amenable as well (just average an invariant probability measure on $H$ over $G$). More generally, if 
$$
1\to H\to G\to K\to 1
$$
is a short exact sequence (of topological groups) and $H, K$ are amenable then $G$ is amenable as well. This will be covered in any book discussing amenable groups.